# How to display pop up window

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, popupwindow

How to display pop up window after successful or failure submitting form in vuejs.

currently i am just displaying  alert message after submitting form. i need to display pop up window with css.

```
          .then(function (response) {
                self.output = response.data;

               //console.log(self.output);
                  if(self.output){
              alert("succesfuly added ");
              }
            else{
              alert("failed added ")
            }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a div with the contents of the pop up. v-if the div and display it as required. Style the div using css.

```
<div v-if="displayPopUp">
 <slot />
</div>
```

```
data() {
 return {
  displayPopUp = false
 }
}
```

```
.then(()=>(this.displayPopUp = true))
```

Change value of displayPopUp after pop up action is completed.

Comment: i am not getting. how to display message in it..about success or failure.